# Is there a way to update argument for each call of lapply?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I'm using a function to update my dataframe, the first argument is the dataframe which I want to update, the second one is another dataframe which allows me to update the first one and the third argument is an integer.

I've already used lapply and other function which are similar but in this case I have some trouble to achieve what I want.

Here is an example of my dataframe :

```
df <- data.frame("Fa" = c("a", "b", "c", "a"),
                 "P" = c(1, 2, 3, 4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Same for the other dataframe:

```
df2 <- data.frame("CF" = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  "R" = c(1, 2, 3),
                  "ND" = c(1, 2, 3),
                  "DD" = c(1, 2, 3),
                  "DF" = c(1, 2, 3),
                  "NF" = c(1, 2, 3),
                  "AAA" = c(1, 2, 3),
                  "BBB" = c(1, 2, 3),
                  "CCC" = c(1, 2, 3),
                  "DDD" = c(1, 2, 3),
                  "EEE" = c(1, 2, 3),
                  "FFF" = c(1, 2, 3),
                  "S" = c(1, 2, 3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The function I'm using :

```
my_function <- function(x, y, nb) {
  x[which(x$Fam == as.character(y[nb, "CF"])), "PR"] <- x[which(x$Fam == as.character(y[nb, "CF"])), "P"] * (1 - as.double(y[nb, "R"]))
  x[which(x$Fa == as.character(y[nb, "CF"])), "R"] <- y[nb, "R"]
  x[which(x$Fa == as.character(y[nb, "CF"])), "ND"] <- y[nb, "ND"]
  x[which(x$Fa == as.character(y[nb, "CF"])), "DD"] <- y[nb, "DD"]
  x[which(x$Fa == as.character(y[nb, "CF"])), "DF"] <- y[nb, "DF"]
  x[which(x$Fa == as.character(y[nb, "CF"])), "NF"] <- y[nb, "NF"]
  x[which(x$Fa == as.character(y[nb, "CF"])), "S"] <- y[nb, "S"]
  return (x)
}
```

Example to see how the function is used :

```
df <- my_function(df, df2, 1)
df <- my_function(df, df2, 2)
df <- my_function(df, df2, 3)
```

Basically my aim is to avoid calling my function multiple times, so it's more clear why i've done it 3 times, it's because in my dataframe "df2" i have 3 rows. So I wanted to know if this could be achieve by using lapply or any other method or should I change my function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a left join and `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df, df2, by  = c("Fa" = "CF")) %>% 
  mutate(PR = P*(1 - R))
#>   Fa P R ND DD DF NF S PR
#> 1  a 1 1  1  1  1  1 1  0
#> 2  b 2 2  2  2  2  2 2 -2
#> 3  c 3 3  3  3  3  3 3 -6
#> 4  a 4 1  1  1  1  1 1  0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i can't really use a function like merge, I used just an example but in my function i'm also doing another operation which cannot be achieve with the merge function

Comment: @Arkning in such a case could you please update your example so that it would be obvious why join won't work? Otherwise it's hard to suggest you anything

Comment: @Arkning It looks like in any case you should start with `left_join`. Does `mutate` solve your problem?

Comment: Even though I wanted to learn another way of doing it, it works so thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Just is it possible to change some column names while joining the data ?

Comment: @Arkning you can always change names before the join. Look at dplyr's `rename` function for example.